# skypeforlinux crashes the keyboard

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, keyboard, skype, crash

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.0.4 and after that skypeforlinux in several ways. I can use Skype to type messages, everything its OK, but when I make a call it crashes the keyboard. After that, I can't do anything on the keyboard. I have to sign out or quit from Skype to get back to normal. I googled it and didn't find anything similar. Is it just me?

My PC is Lenovo thinkpad L470 , I installed Ubuntu 18.0.4 and the latest version of Skype.

If anyone could help I would appreciate it a lot and if you want any other information about the environment let me know.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I experience the same issue on my ThinkPad E580 running Kubuntu 19.10. Did you find a fix for this yet?

Comment: I haven't yet, but back in the past i used to have skypeforlinux working on ubuntu 16.0.4 perfectly in the same laptop

Comment: Same here on my ThinkPad E540 running Ubuntu 18.04. I have realized that, after finishing the call, putting the computer to sleep fixes the issue. But it's pretty annoying not to be able to move the mouse or write things while in a call

Comment: yes, I have also come across this issue. for me the keyboard gets stuck *only* if I do 1 to 1 call. it works all fine if I am on a group call. still looking for a fix.

Comment: Same issue here on Debian testing on Thinkpad E470. Keyboard crashes only while and after a video call.

Comment: Are you able to get the output of `dmesg | tail` after this happens and put it in the  OP @ckaloger

Comment: Seems it's got fixed in recent versions of `skypeforlinux`. Upgrade Skype to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly the similar issue. Although the problem is still not fixed, I understood the pattern that is causing the error for me. It is function key combination (Fn-F1 to Fn-F12 that can be used as shortcuts for volume +/- etc.) that is trigering the problem on my ThinkPad E480 with Ubuntu 18.04 and skypeforlinux (current version).

I know it is not a fix, but a workaround to avoid the error.